# XSL to XML removing data betwee {}

Tags: xml, xslt

I am processing XSL+XML-> HTML using XSLTproc

having a problem with some info being removed in the process.

XSL:

```
<div item="{id}">
```

IS TURNING INTO:

HTML:

```
<div item="">
```

I need the result to be:

HTML:

```
<div item="{id}">
```

Any ideas how to fix/or prevent this?

Comment: Could you post your XSLT code and XML?

Comment: You just have to escape the { and } characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just double the `{}` :

**XSLT**

```
<div item="{{id}}">
```

**Result**

```
<div item="{id}">
```

Comment: awesome. Thanks for the newbie help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having in your current XSLT is that it is being treated as an Attribute Value Template. The curly braces tell XSLT that it is an expression to be evaluated, and in your case it will be evaluated as the value of the **id** element, which if it doesn't exist, will be blank.

To literally output `<div item="{id}">` you could do either of the following:

```
<div item="{'{id}'}">
</div>
```

Or:

```
<div>
   <xsl:attribute name="item">{id}</xsl:attribute>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do in your XSLT is:

```
<div>
    <xsl:attribute name="item"><xsl:text>{id}</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
</div>
```